# Cannot create inner beanof type org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator error while Spring boot application deployed on aws

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have deployed multitenant Spring boot application on AWS EC2. the code just works fine in the local system, but application is failing with below error after docker run in aws ec2.

```
] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderReportListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/app-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aic/autofluence/appservice/scheduler/kafkaReportListener/OrderReportListener.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reportFactoryImplData' defined in URL [jar:file:/app-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aic/autofluence/appservice/scheduler/service/Impl/ReportFactoryImplData.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderReportRepository' defined in com.aic.autofluence.appservice.scheduler.repository.OrderReportRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TenantDatabaseConfig: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4293e066' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4293e066': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2021-05-10 18:58:57.081  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'masterdb-persistence-unit'
2021-05-10 18:58:57.082  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : masterdb-connection-pool - Shutdown initiated...
2021-05-10 18:58:57.099  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : masterdb-connection-pool - Shutdown completed.
2021-05-10 18:58:57.103  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-05-10 18:58:57.124  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-10 18:58:57.147 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.aic.autofluence.appservice.scheduler.service.Impl.ReportFactoryImplData required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Sample code I have as below:

**tenantConfig: The EntityManagerFactory bean itself is not recognised. it is working good in local system, failing same in vm**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "x.x.x.x.scheduler.repository", "x.x.x.x.scheduler.model" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"x.x.x.x..scheduler.repository", "x.x.x.x..scheduler.service"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "tenantEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "tenantTransactionManager")
public class TenantDatabaseConfig {

   @Bean(name = "tenantJpaVendorAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ();
    }

    @Bean(name = "tenantTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("tenantEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory tenantEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager ();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(tenantEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
    public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name = "currentTenantIdentifierResolver")
    public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
        return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
    }

    
    @Bean(name = "tenantEntityManagerFactory")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
                    MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
            @Qualifier("currentTenantIdentifierResolver")
                    CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ();
        //All tenant related entities, repositories and service classes must be scanned
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.aic.autofluence.appservice");
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("tenantdb-persistence-unit");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put( Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put( Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
        properties.put( Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
        properties.put( Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put( Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        properties.put( Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        properties.put( Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return emfBean;
    }
}


**MasterConfig: It is configured properly working fine**

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"x.x.x.x.mastertenant.model",
        "x.x.x.x.mastertenant.repository"
},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager")
public class MasterDatabaseConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterDatabaseConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private MasterDatabaseConfigProperties masterDbProperties;

    @Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource ();
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(masterDbProperties.getUsername());
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(masterDbProperties.getPassword());
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(masterDbProperties.getUrl());
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName(masterDbProperties.getDriverClassName());
        hikariDataSource.setPoolName(masterDbProperties.getPoolName());
        // HikariCP settings
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(masterDbProperties.getMaxPoolSize());
        hikariDataSource.setMinimumIdle(masterDbProperties.getMinIdle());
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(masterDbProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
        hikariDataSource.setIdleTimeout(masterDbProperties.getIdleTimeout());
        LOG.info("Setup of masterDataSource succeeded.");
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ();
        em.setDataSource(masterDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{x,x,x,x...});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("masterdb-persistence-unit");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        LOG.info("Setup of masterEntityManagerFactory succeeded.");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(@Qualifier("masterEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager ();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor ();
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
        return properties;
    }
```

Any Idea what might be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Any one have an idea on this?

Comment: Did you mean to have two periods in the package path above in "x.x.x.x..scheduler.repository". This might have just occurred while you were redacting, but just checking.

Comment: @Atmas x.x.x.x.. is the package names Since I am not allowed to exposed that, I just put some random data like x.x.x.x... the question I have asked is related to the bean creation. Could you please comment on that if you have any idea?

Comment: @Atmas regarding redacting is not an issue here. bean creation is not happening , what I observed is in the TenantDatabaseConfig class,  bean related to MasterDatabaseConfig is pointed, that itself is nt getting recognized in the TenantDatabaseConfig class. If have any idea on this on why, please do comment on this

Comment: I'm wondering if this might just be a convention over configuration conflict. Would you be willing to replace all instances of your bean name and refs to it of "tenantEntityManagerFactory" with just "entityManagerFactory"? That way, it's consistent with the method name (which is entityManagerFactory) and consistent with other examples I've seen online.

Comment: @Atmas tried that, not working

Comment: Ok, have you tried testing without the @ConditionalOnBean filters to see if they're being filtered out?

Comment: @Atmas yes ,tahttime only understood it not recognizing the MasterDatabaseConfig details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232356/discussion-between-atmas-and-arundhathi-d).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by removing the @ConditionalOnBean annotation. Thanks for the people who responded.

Comment: Strange. What changed from the time we talked about it earlier today but it didn't recognize the details? The earlier test wasn't fully deployed or something? Glad you're back online.

Comment: But you mentioned,"`the code just works fine in the local system, `". If `@ConditionalOnBean` breaks your app from running, how come it "`works fine in the local system`"?

Comment: @justthink  that was actually my question. In aws why ConditionalOnBean annotation is not working. Still I am bugging some articles reaching out people on the same. Now Since it is able to recognize the bean by removing the  ConditionalOnBean, I took up that . If you have any idea or explination on that, please do comment here

Comment: @Atmas everthing is deployed. I started debugging again by keeping log statements in each line in tenantDatabaseConfig. what I found was classes are getting scanned properly  but the moment it points to ConditionalOnBean annotation in the app which is deployed on aws not getting processed. So tried removing that annotation and tried in my local first it worked fine in recognizing the bean, same deployed worked in VM also

Comment: Actually works. Struggled with this for the last two days. Thanks

Comment: Would still love to know what the hell is going on. Why only happen on deployment and not local environment.

Comment: @KelvinMuia I am looking for the answer for the same. I am trying from my side, Once I figure out Definitely I will comment here

Answer (score -2):

> the code just works fine in the local system, but application is failing with below error after docker run in aws ec2.

Could you make sure that you have tried `mvn clean package` and deployed the lastest artifacts to EC2?

---

Judging from stacktrace, there is a missing bean of name: `entityManagerFactory`. You need to refer to this bean with the correct name.

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.aic.autofluence.appservice.scheduler.service.Impl.ReportFactoryImplData required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

In your code ,

```java
 @Primary
    @Bean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactory() {
 // ...
   @Bean(name = "tenantEntityManagerFactory")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
// ...
```

Multiple beans are of the same **type** `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and of different **names**: `masterEntityManagerFactory` and `tenantEntityManagerFactory`.

If you wish to reference the bean by **type** instead of by **name**, you cannot do it because you have multiple beans of the same **type** `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. To explicitly tell Spring which bean to inject, specify the bean name per your defination.

Based on your stack trace, you referenced the bean by the name `entityManagerFactory` in a constructor. To fix this, you need to change the argument name from `entityManagerFactory` to either `masterEntityManagerFactory` or `tenantEntityManagerFactory`.

Another way to specify which bean name you wish to inject, is to use `@Qualifier("beanName")`. [Useful Guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)

Comment: @justhtink here I am refering bean by argument name only . I am not getting where exactly you are pointing out @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"x.x.x.x..scheduler.repository", "x.x.x.x..scheduler.service"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "tenantEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "tenantTransactionManager")

Comment: Search globally for `entityManagerFactory`, make it case sensitive.

Comment: @Arundhathi D  There is no way that exactly the same `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation breaks bean creation in AWS EC2 server whilst not breaking bean creation in the local system. You got the question wrong.

Comment: try once mutitenant app by providing ConditionalOnBean annotation. If you are facing the same issue it is well and good and let me know also. I don;t think question is wring here. Thanks